# How to import module from other directory in python

Tags: python

I have a file tree like this:

```
app
|---src
|    |---vlep/config.py
|
|---tests
     |---conftest.py
```

from conftest.py I am trying to `import vlep.confi as config` and I am getting the `ModulenotFoundError: No module named 'vlep'`. I am using venv and I added absolute paths for `app`, `src` and `vlep` directories to `venv/bin/activate`, so when I activate the virtualenv I can have these directories in the PYTHONPATH env. I thought that this would do the job, but no...and have no idea why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `import ..src.vlep.config as config`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the file path manually to import the modules from another directory. You can assign a directory path to the PYTHONPATH variable and still get your program working.

In Linux, you can use the following command in the terminal to set the path:

```
export PYTHONPATH='path/to/directory'
```

In Windows system :

```
SET PYTHONPATH='path/to/directory'
```

To see if PYTHONPATH variable holds the path of the new folder, you can use the following command:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

Then you can do your imports:

```
from conftest import vlep.confi as config
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the path to the `src` folder in `sys.path` like this:

```py
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, f'{os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}/../src')

from vlep import config
```

This way the absolute path to your `src` directory will be first when Python resolves where to import the module from. And it also does not matter what directory you run `conftest.py` from.

Answer (score 0):

Tks for your time guys. After all there was not wronging to what I was doing to allow the import. The `export PYTHONPATH=":/home/user/app/src/vlep"` added to the end of `venv/bin/activate` was enough. The problem was that I was running a script that was changing the value of PYTHONPATH.